# Hero-unit not displaying right

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I cant get this hero-unit to move center like on http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/examples/hero.html# with this original CSS -

```
.hero-unit {
  padding: 60px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 200;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: inherit;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  border:1px solid #cacaca;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
     -moz-border-radius: 10px;
          border-radius: 10px;
}
```

See what I did on http://www.magnixsolutions.com/dev/test/test.html

My CSS is the same as the original file below. I dont understand whats going on.

```
.hero-unit {
  padding: 60px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 200;
  line-height: 30px;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  border:1px solid #cacaca;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
         -moz-border-radius: 10px;
          border-radius: 10px;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed two things 1 is

//From hero.html source code

```
body {
   padding-top: 60px;
   padding-bottom: 40px;
}
```

And other is

```
.container,
  .navbar-static-top .container,
  .navbar-fixed-top .container,
  .navbar-fixed-bottom .container {
    width: 1170px;
}
```

The above css is from http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css

Use above and then check.

Answer (score 0):

You missed something vital on the Bootstrap example page:

```
  body {
    padding-top: 60px;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
  }
```

Because the navbar is fixed to the top, you'll need to push the body content down so it starts after the navbar. In your case, a top-padding of 80px seems more appropriate.

Btw, `jquery` isn't really a useful tag for your question.

Answer (score 0):

You have fixed  header and need to set padding-top on body tag.